# Rails Model Relationships, user roles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, orm

I asked a similar question a couple of days ago, but I realized that I didn't ask it quite right.
In a Rails app with Manager and Employee models, let's say that all managers are employees, but not all employees are managers. I needed a solution for a user to be able to act as a manager and employee, both having different attributes and methods.

I was told to use Single Table Inheritance, which is very useful, but that gave the user the properties of both at the same time. What I would like is for the user (not every user) to be able to act as a manager and employee, but not both at the same time.
So, some users can either be a manager or employee, but not both. Some users can only be an employee.

Any ideas on what relationship I should use for this?

Comment: You can set a `type` attribute in `users` table which stores two values `manager` and `employee`.Then you can call `User.where(:type => 'manager')` or `User.where(:type => 'employee')` to differentiate the users.

Comment: What if I wanted the employees to have different attributes and methods than the managers?

Comment: "all managers are employees" ... "be able to act as a manager and employee, but not both at the same time." ... "some users can either be a manager or employee, but not both" <<< That's too contradictory.

Comment: I meant a manager acts as a manager to their employees, but acts as an employee to their manager/boss.

Answer (score 0):

You could use STI like so:

#### structure

```
create_table :users do |t|
  t.string :name
  t.string :type # index this
end
```

#### source

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attributes -- name, type

  def to_s
    "#{name} (Generic User)"
  end
end

class Manager < User
  def to_s
    "#{name} (Manager)"
  end
end

class Employee < User
  def to_s
    "#{name} (Employee)"
  end
end
```

#### examples

```
puts User.new(name: "Mr User")
# => "Mr User (Generic User)"

puts Manager.new(name: "Mr Manager")
# => "Mr Manager (Manager)"

puts Employee.new(name: "Mr Employee")
# => "Mr Employee (Employee)"
```

Comment: So you are suggesting I would either log in the user from the employees or managers table?

Comment: @user3806756 when using STI, there is no employees or managers table, there is just users table, with a type column. What you use internally to login the user is entirely up to you. I would use User model for generic operations (authentication), but Employee/Manager for specific stuff like authorization (where employee/manager would act as roles). I don't really know enough about your application to make a relevant suggestion.